# Inequality type question from Gamelin's Book

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ be an analytic function for $\lvert z\rvert<1$ and satisfies $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leq M$. Show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lvert a_n\rvert^2\leq M^2$. The hint is given to integrate $\lvert f(z)\rvert^2$ around a circle of radius $r<1$.
Obviously we have,
\begin{align}
 \int_{\lvert z\rvert =r} \lvert f(z)\rvert^2\lvert dz\rvert \leq M^22\pi r
\end{align}
If I can then show that this is integral on the left is larger than the sum $2\pi\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lvert a_n\rvert^2\lvert r\lvert^{2n}$ and then pass to the limit as $r\nearrow 1$, then we will be done. However, I can not see for the life of me why this is in fact true.  I would appreciate any assistance. Also this question is in the section of the book on the Schwarz Lemma, but I fail to see how that is at all related to this exercise.

Comment: Expand $|f(z)|^2=f(z)\bar f(z)$ and integrate term by term noting that by periodicity only the diagonal terms are non zero so the integral is exactly the required sum